# Joint cumulative density of two dependent RVs

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. Let $\alpha$ be given in $[0,1]$.

I am asked to calculate
\begin{equation}
\text{Pr}(X+Y+Z>\alpha \;\;\; \& \;\;\; X+Y\leq \alpha) 
\end{equation}
This is what I have so far:
\begin{equation}
f_{X+Y+Z,X+Y}(u,v)=f_{Z,X+Y}(u-v,v)=f_{Z}(u-v)\cdot f_{X+Y}(v),
\end{equation}
because $Z$ and $X+Y$ are now independent. Let's say I know the densities of both $Z$ and $X+Y$ which are uniform and Irwin-Hall respectively.
Hence, 
\begin{equation}
F_{Z,X+Y}(w,v)=F_{Z}(w)\cdot F_{X+Y}(v)=\text{Pr}(Z\leq w \;\;\; \& \;\;\; X+Y\leq v)
\end{equation}

I'm stuck here, how can I relate the joint, cumulative distribution to what I'm asked to calculate?

Comment: $P(X+Y+Z>\alpha,X+Y\leq \alpha)=\int_{\alpha}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\alpha f_{X+Y+Z,X+Y}(u,v)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$.

Comment: Okay. Does your answer intrinsically confirm that $f_{X+Y+Z,X+Y}(u,v)=f_{Z,X+Y}(u-v,v)=f_{Z}(u-v)\cdot f_{X+Y}(v)$?

Comment: It does not. It stems from the fact that for any random variables $X$ and $Y$; $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P((X,Y)\in A\times B)=\iint_{A\times B}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$.

Comment: I completely agree to that. But do you agree with that equation, I know it holds for the discrete case. I'm asking because I'm having no luck so far...